# how to transfer user from one MIDLET to another MIDLET

Tags: java-me, midp

I have created an menu in which there are different operation. When the user click's on the item's it should invoke another midlet respectively.

Or is there any other way of doing it?

I tried this code: `previous = PushRegistry.registerAlarm("m", 0);` to transfer to another midlet but it gives an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No MIDLet-<n> registration
```

`m` is the midlet present in the same package.

Comment: can you show the code you tried? preferably in [SSCCE form](http://www.sscce.org/ "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example")

Comment: i tried this code "previous = PushRegistry.registerAlarm("m", 0);" to transfer to another midlet but it gives an exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No MIDLet-<n> registration??

Comment: m is the midlet present in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

[API documentation for the method PushRegistry.registerAlarm](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/PushRegistry.html#registerAlarm%28java.lang.String,%20long%29) explains why you are getting the error:

> **Throws:**
>   ...ClassNotFoundException - if the MIDlet class name can not be found in the current MIDlet suite or if this class is not included in any of the MIDlet-<n> records in the descriptor file or the jar file manifest or if the midlet argument is null...

Given the error message about `No MIDLet-<n> registration`, one of the possible error reasons listed above appears to fit your case: **"class is not included in any of the MIDlet-<n> records"**.

- If you are interested in how to properly use PushRegistry functionality, consider studying introductory tutorial, like eg one recommended at [Learning Path: Getting Started with MIDP 2.0](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/learn/midp/midp20/):

> [The MIDP 2.0 Push Registry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/) is a comprehensive article that shows you how to get your MIDP 2.0 application to respond to incoming network connections...

Comment: its tooo complicated. I could'nt understand. Can u tell me simple words how to invoke a midlet program(b.java) form a midlet program(a.java). Where a.java and b.java are present inside the same folder(default folder) in ecliplse IDE.

Comment: @venkatsantoshd do you mean the most basic java method call, something like `new b().someMethod()`?

Comment: I mean the both a.java and b.java are the midlets.

Comment: @venkatsantoshd why do you need them both be midlets? the way you describe it, this looks not needed at all for eg b.java to be midlet (no need to `extend MIDlet`)

Comment: k.. I got it.
one more doubt which is the easiest way to draw an XY graph in the JSP.

Comment: @venkatsantoshd regarding _XY graph in the JSP_ it is a [different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "'chameleon questions' are not welcome at SO"). Ask separately if you're interested in it